# Is there any way I can dress as Bruce Wayne?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

While playing Arkham Knight on my PS4, I went to Wayne Tower where I found Lucius Fox and his secretary. The secretary was sitting in another room. The game play won't allow me to go in as Batman. Is there any way I can dress as Bruce Wayne in the game?

Answer (score 3):

You have to enter the Wayne Tower through the basement elevator ( if the mission you are referring is 'friend in need' ) Going from the Wayne tower balcony wont help. I think you have to defeat the tanks in the basement first and then approach the elevator. Make sure you're near the right Wayne tower.